# Velleman Sound to Light Kit Questions

Tags: circuit-design

I recently purchased a Velleman [Sound to Light](http://www.vellemanusa.com/products/view/?country=us&lang=enu&id=350678) soldering kit. I thought it would be easy to understand even as a beginner electronic hobbyist but I am having some issues.

Please take a moment to check out the kit schematics:

[image]

I have limited knowledge about how all these works but there are some parts of the circuit that are particularly troublesome for me to understand. Here are a couple of questions:

1. What is the purpose of the C4 capacitor? Is this what it's known as the bulk or smoothing capacitor?
2. Why does't the T3 transistor have a resistor on the emitter leg? Don't you need that resistor (for negative feedback) to be able to stabilize the transistor such as preventing thermal overrun, minimize beta variations effects between transistors etc?
3. What is the purpose of resistor R8? It looks like its on a weird place being in series between the power supply positive lead and and half of the circuit, what is up with that?
4. What is the point of having R12 and R5 as two separate resistors? Can't those two resistor be replace with a single resistor and achieve the same affect?
5. Why aren't the biasing resistors (voltage dividers) on T1 and T2 not identical? Its the exact same transistor so why is the voltage divider biasing different (specifically on R2 and R10)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the purpose of the C4 capacitor? Is this what it's known as the bulk or smoothing capacitor? What is the purpose of resistor R8? It looks like its on a weird place being in series between the power supply positive lead and and half of the circuit, what is up with that?

As @respawnedFluff explained, its likely a simple RC filter.

> Why does't the T3 transistor have a resistor on the emitter leg? Don't you need that resistor (for negative feedback) to be able to stabilize the transistor such as preventing thermal overrun, minimize beta variations effects between transistors etc?

No. T3 is acting as a simple Emitter-Follower Switch. It's purpose is to switch T4 On and Off only.

> What is the point of having R12 and R5 as two separate resistors? Can't those two resistor be replace with a single resistor and achieve the same affect?

Not for the intended purpose. R12 is a weak pull-up designed to keep T4 biased to V+, while R5 is a strong pull-down resistor for T4. When T3 is on, T4 is turned on via R5, overriding R12. Otherwise T4's base would be left floating when T3 is turned off.

> Why aren't the biasing resistors (voltage dividers) on T1 and T2 not identical? Its the exact same transistor so why is the voltage divider biasing different (specifically on R2 and R10)?

T1 and T2 are both set up as amplifiers. T1 is a pre-amp boosting the small changes from the mic, while T2 is a second stage amp. Hence the different gain values used. They likely found these values the best for their kit. As @RF commented, they can have the same gain in some situations.

Comment: Saved me from typing the rest :-) Actually regarding the last bit (q5): they don't necessarily need different gains (I've done two 10x gain stages), but these being BJTs they need different bias points for the mid-level/average signal that comes out of the preceding stage.

Comment: @RespawnedFluff noted

Answer (score 1):

Regarding 1 & 3 (i.e the power supply arrangement): Given the position of C4 (which does what you think) it looks like R8 is being used as a filter (poor man's inductor) to keep some noise from from the right/LED-side from getting to the sensitive microphone [+its amp] side. Also the LEDs presumably blink on and off resulting in large variations in current on the right-hand side. And you want to have a sort of basic stabilization on the left side. But a capacitor big enough to well stabilize the LED side (as well) would presumably be much larger & expensive. R8 prevents the C4 capacitor from discharging too quickly toward the right. A voltage regulator separating the two sides would, of course, be a superior solution, but more expensive.